# Can't open an image file when using an ImageIO class

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I've written a program that has to open an image I've placed on the desktop. The problem is that the program runs but nothing happens in the console nor does it open the image. Do I've to implement a GUI to fix the problem or...?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Image {
    public JavaImage() {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/index.jpg"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There isn't a picture in the folder");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Image();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to write up a GUI. Your code right now loads an image and then does nothing with it -- if you want to do something with it (like displaying it in a GUI component), you need to write the code to do that.

Comment: ImageIO isn't magic.  There are image formats that ImageIO can't read.

Comment: @yshavit : Thanks, I used JLabel which fixed the problem :)

Comment: Voting to close, as the code works fine, it just doesn't do anything (as expected)...